# Output of DFT with unitary amplitude

Tags: calculus

I'm considering an operation where I perform the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of a complex vector, and then I simply normalize the elements of the output vector by dividing to their amplitude, i.e. I'm taking as output only the phasors of the DFT output.

Is such operation known and used in Mathematics or I'm the only one applying it? In case it is known, how is it called/referred to?

Comment: Do you mean that you are doing $\mathcal{F}x/\left\Vert \mathcal{F}x\right\Vert $?
Or $\mathcal{F}x/\left|\left[\mathcal{F}x\right]_{0}\right|$ (i.e.
dividing by DC component). Either way, I don't know if there is a
standard name for this.

Comment: I mean normalizing every element by its amplitude, such that the final amplitude of all the elements of the output vector is one.

Comment: I see. So the answer is $v$, where $v_i = \left[\mathcal{F}x\right]_{i}/\left|\left[\mathcal{F}x\right]_{i}\right|$. I don't think this has a name.